# Date Conversion to String

Tags: mysql, sql-server, date

I am trying to extract data from an outside vendor's source database.  I am connecting through a JDBC connection and think (based on the syntax it might be mysql or sql server).  However certain functions dont appear to be working in it.  I have a date.  The datatype of the field is date but doesnt appear to be a true date.  During extraction I see it in the format 2016-12-06 00:00:00.0.

I have tried several functions to convert to string but none of them seem to work.  Anyone have any ideas why database this might be or how I can convert?

I get the error cannot the conversion from date to CHAR is not allowed with case or convert
select load_ts, CONVERT(load_ts, CHAR) as dt_str
from DEX_PROD_ORA_VBL.OPUB_WXDM_TM_PD

select load_ts, CAST(load_ts as CHAR) as dt_str
from DEX_PROD_ORA_VBL.OPUB_WXDM_TM_PD

I get an error the function for date_format is in an unknown form
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d %m %Y') AS your_date;

Any thoughts on what the DB might be or another way to convert to string and reformat

Comment: What do you want to do with this field after you convert it?

Comment: Have you tried VARCHAR instead of CHAR?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with follwing query
SELECT convert(datetime, '2016-12-06 00:00:00.0', 120) or
SELECT convert(datetime, '2016-12-06 00:00:00.0', 121)

Comment: datetime does not appear to be a function within this database date is or timestamp and neither of which works with convert.  It is expecting a string.  However VARCHAR does work instead of CHAR  thank you @digital.aaron